# Remove string with brackets in List (Python)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list

```
thislist = ["apple (red)", "banana (yellow)", "cherry (red)"]
```

How do I remove/strip off the brackets in each item of the list?

**Desire Output:**

```
thislist = ["apple red", "banana yellow", "cherry red"]
```

Thank you

Comment: Please do add your tried code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
newlist = []
for nn in thislist:
    newlist.append(nn.replace('(','').replace(')',''))
newlist
```

Output:

```
['apple red', 'banana yellow', 'cherry red']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use translate()

```
>>> thislist = ["apple (red)", "banana (yellow)", "cherry (red)"]
>>> 
>>> bad_char_dict = {"(": "", ")": ""}
>>> table = str.maketrans(bad_char_dict)
>>> 
>>> new_list = []
>>> for item in thislist:
...     new_list.append(item.translate(table))
>>> 
>>> new_list
['apple red', 'banana yellow', 'cherry red']
```